# Dynamic form insert SQL php while using jAutoCalc

Tags: php, sql, forms, dynamic

I need some help please.

I am using http://c17r.github.io/jAutoCalc/sample.html.

I am stuck on getting the array data into SQL.

```
$a = 1;

while($a <= count($_POST[‘qty’])
{
$query= "INSERT INTO tblsitem(item, qty, price) values ('$_POST['item']', '$_POST['qty']', '$_POST[[‘price']')";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query or die ('Error');   
$a++;   // incrementing value of a by 1
}
```

I tried foreach, but as soon as I add key [] to field name, the jAutoCalc onscreen does not work anymore.

Any input will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: if I use print_r ($_POST['qty']), it shows only the 1st value of form and not the array.  How do I get all the values from the form.  Thanks for any input.

Comment: Echo count($_POST[‘qty’]); gives an error.